# Launch app in splitscreen mode from command line

Tags: multi-window

How to launch activity in splitscreen mode with the `am` command in Android terminal or Termux?

Say I want to launch the "Material Files" explorer, I run:

```
am start -n me.zhanghai.android.files/.filelist.FileListActivity
```

but it launches in fullscreen.

How to make it splitscreen? Also, it would be best if I can customize launching on top/bottom half.